# How can I extinguish myself?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

My SpEn had the pleasure of killing Azrael and part of his escort. However, this involved sticky flames, that burned off all of my scrolls and shattered a few potions. Luckily, my +2 robe of fire resistance helped survive me the experience. I do grieve the scrolls however, and it doesn't help that part of the escort was a mottled dragon, which now attached me sticky flames of its own.

How can I put sticky flames off myself?

Comment: Crawl is totally awesome!  Did you look through the newsgroup archive?  I'll have a browse.  They were quite active...

Comment: Hmmm.  Sadly enough, napalm can continue to burn even in the presence of water.  I don't know the answer to this one...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you've been set aflame, there is only one way to extinguish yourself: stepping onto a water square (including fountains). This is guaranteed and has immediate effect; oddly, you don't need to step into the water, levitating above it is fine.

Conservation is checked on each potential item destruction, so if you wear an amulet of conservation while aflame, you reduce the chance of every surviving item being destroyed by 90% each turn.

(Source: reading the DCSS 0.8 source code.)

Comment: No change in DCSS 0.9.

Answer (score -3):

You can also take of an armour.

Comment: Do you have any source to back this up?